# Is it possible to force close html5 video player on iOS devices?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, video

I'm trying to have a fullscreen video close when it ends on iOS, while it works in inspect and desktop it doesnt work on my iPhone.

here is my Jquery:

```
$('#video > video').on('ended',function(){
    vidOn = false;
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    $( '#video > video' ).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    $( '#video > video' ).get(0).pause();
    $( '#video' ).fadeOut();
    finalpage();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `$('#video > video').webkitExitFullScreen()` works for you?